# Refactoring Problem XCode 4.0.1

Tags: objective-c, refactoring

So i was trying to refactor the name of a class in XCode following the steps in my text book. I'm sure I'm doing everything right and I downloaded XCode off the App Store. Basically, whenever I right-click -> refactor -> name -> preview, xcode crashes. Here's the error:

`ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFoundation/DVTFoundation-227/Framework/Classes/Utilities/DVTTask.m:208`

Details:  The launch path must be set before launching.

Object:

Method:   -launchRunningTerminationHandlerOnQueue:error:terminationHandler:

Thread:   {name = (null), num = 15}

Hints:   None

Any Ideas?

Thanks

P.S., sorry, i dont know how to using the quotes

EDIT: Fixed. I reinstalled with the package in side resources under "Show Package Contents" -> Resources -> XCODE and IOS SDK

Comment: As a general warning, XCode 4 crashes in subtle and bizarre ways. Its getting better on every release but its not perfect yet.

Comment: Yeah I realized that, but luckily I was able to fix it. As a warning to everyone else also, XCode broke my back-ups in iTunes, I had to reinstall iTunes, but if you install with the method above^, it doesn't. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Xcode itself crashes, that's a bug in Xcode and you should [report it](http://bugreporter.apple.com/). Using the Refactor command to rename a class definitely works at least some of the time -- I just tried it twice with Xcode 4.0.1 and the preview comes up with no problem.

I'd suggest creating a new project and trying the Refactor command there. If it works and doesn't crash, then your existing project may have something to do with the problem. If it doesn't work, that might suggest that the problem is related to your Xcode installation or machine configuration. This is just an attempt to help you find a way to work around the issue, though... Again, if Xcode is crashing, then there's a problem in Xcode.

Comment: Yeah, im reinstalling now. After that I'll report it, i realized it also broke my iTunes syncing after the install, so i probably messed up the install. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:
**Quit and restart Xcode** before *every* attempt to use 'Refactor'.

For me on Lion running Xcode 4.4.1, a Refactor causes a crash every time if I've been doing any work. Even the simplest 'Rename' operation results in a crash.

If I restart Xcode, and make my first operation a 'Refactor', it works every time.

Further tip: It's a good time to make a backup, while quit before running a Refactor.

Comment: Restarting Xcode did not work for me, it crashes every refactor. Running Xcode 4.6 on Mountain Lion.