# Can Not Refactor Class Name in XCode

Tags: xcode4.6, automated-refactoring

I am trying to rename the class name for a view controller (which has an associated `.xib` file) via XCode's refactoring tool. After entering a new name, I get this error message (no preview of changes):

> **The selection is not a type that can be renamed.**
>
> Make a different selection and try again.

I have tried all the suggestions in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5527484/620197) thread, but no luck.

What could prevent XCode from being able to refactor a class (and related file names), when other classes and variables can be refactored without any problem?

Comment: I recommend filing an issue on bugreporter.apple.com.  Xcode's refactoring feature is not a strong suit of the IDE.  I have begun using AppCode instead for refactoring when feasible.

Comment: @ctpenrose At this point, I am going to wait for XCode 5 to be released. I thought about AppCode, and I find refactoring is its only string point, but not worth $99.

Answer (score 0):

I think you tried to change the classname by selecting the file and press refactor or you select it in the #import "classname".

Instead try to select "classname" in the interface definition after @interface

Comment: I am selecting the class name in the interface declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem
Here is my solution

`Move the whole Project to another place Then it works(to me)`